# Не работает калькулятор на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Основная проблема в том, что нельзя вывести ни одну цифру,кроме той которая в resulte, как решить ? Также извините за картинку, сам код не вставляется.

[image: Код]

Comment: Непонятно вообще ничего. И код здесь отлично вставляется, не нужны картинки

Comment: Рискну предположить по не очень четко поставленному вопросу, что кавычки при выполнении арифметических операций не нужны, т.е. например `result = x-y`

Comment: 1) Чтобы делать скриншоты есть `Print Screen`, а на windows приложение "Ножницы" 2) вас уже в вашем предыдущем вопросе просили вставлять кодом в вопрос, а не картинками

Comment: Да что вы на человека набросились? Может быть он не умел до этого пользоваться компьютером, а сейчас изучает... Вместо того, чтобы человеку все высказывать, лучше бы объяснили, как это делается. Будьте терпимее, господа!

Answer (score 1):

У тебя в каждом условии переменной result присваивается строковая переменная. Просто убери ковычки в операции каждого результа

```
result = 'x + y' # не верно
result = x + y   # верно
```